# Initialization error after moving installation of CiviCRM for Wordpress from localhost to Server

Tags: wordpress

I've just moved an installation from my localhost setup to my server on Nearlyfreespeech.

I've moved everything over and changed everything having followed [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/).

I initially got an error related to the civicrm.setttings.php file. I fixed this by following this [advice](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=26131.0).

Now I'm getting another error. It says 'Initialization Error' Warning: fopen(/home/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/../files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.f446a1fd9c619d6abf51f11bf29f358c.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Log/file.php on line 216.

Full error at the url: http://logistics.nfshost.com/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

might want to delete the contents of the ConfigAndLog directory and start clean on the new server:

% rm -rf /home/public/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

You probably need to root access and/or do the above operation as your webserver userid (which probably is the owner of the aboe directory)

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I delete everything in that folder I just get the following error: Warning: file_put_contents(/home/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/../files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/.htaccess): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/File.php on line 436

Fatal error: Call to a member function url() on a non-object in /home/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php on line 254